# GIF animation with ImageMagick and many images

Tags: bash, animation, imagemagick, gif

I'm trying to create an GIF animation with ImageMagick using multiple source jpg images. Here is the command line call I make

```
convert -delay 20 -loop 0 $WDir/*.jpg -resize 20% $WDir/animate.gif
```

where `$WDir` is a bash variable that points to the working directory where all the images are located. The script runs fine for say 10 images, but I have 500+ images I want to animate. I don't want to `resize` the images any less and I've tried to limit the memory usage, but that didn't seem to help.

Can someone tell me how I would go about animating a significant amount of images without sacrificing image quality while using a machine with limited RAM (16GB)? If it needs to be done in "chunks", that's fine, as I can write a bash script to do the work and "set it and forget it".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is your Imagemagick version and what is the platform? I assume Unix (Linux or Mac). What error are you getting? If you are running out of memory, then you can adjust your policy.xml file so that you can use disk rather than RAM, but it will take longer to process. You may need to process in batches as you have said. Also depending upon your OS, the string of image names may exceed an OS limit (typical for Windows).

My suggestion would be to process all the images using mogrify, since it process them one at a time, so no significant RAM usage. Use mogrify to resize and reformat. Once done you can probably load all the gifs into RAM and make the animation. I would suggest you create a new directory to hold the output from mogrify and use the -path argument to specify that output directory. The directory needs to be created first. So

```
cd to directory holding your input images
mogrify -path yourpath2/newdirectory -format gif -resize 20% *.jpg
```

Then once that is done

```
cd to newdirectory
convert -delay 20 *.gif -loop 0 animate.gif
```

Comment: I'm running it right now and so far so good. One question though...assume that I can't load all the gifs into RAM. What would I do in this case?

Comment: O and yes, I'm doing this on a Linux. My version is ImageMagick 6.3.6, which I realize needs to be updated, but I believe the necessary commands should be available. If there are new commands as of version 7.*, then I'll be sure to update ImageMagick.

Comment: To avoid overloading RAM use mogrify as describe above, which should work fine on your version of Imagemagick. Imagemagick 7 has new features, but also has some syntax differences. For example in place of convert use magick. In place of mogrify, use magick mogrify. I am not sure any Linux distributions come with IM 7, yet. So you may have to install from RPM or from source. But you can probably get a new Linux distribution with an upgrade of IM 6.

Comment: Yeah I follow you with `mogrify`, as in it operates on one file at a time to save RAM, but in your solution you say "Once done you can probably load all the gifs into RAM and make the animation". What I was asking in my first comment was in reference to this statement. What if I can not load all the gifs resulting from `mogrify`into RAM at once?

Comment: If you do not have enough RAM, then Imagemagick will page to disk. This will slow it down, but it will finish. You can set the amount of disk space used via the policy.xml file. See http://www.imagemagick.org/script/resources.php#configure and http://www.imagemagick.org/script/resources.php#environment

Comment: OK, I think I follow. Hypothetically, say I have 10 million jpgs. I can follow your steps above, using the first 1M images, to create "animate_1.gif" on RAM. I can then repeat, using the next 1M images, to create "animate_2.gif" on RAM, etc. In the end, I can make a final call to `convert` to "stitch" all the "animate_*.gif" files, which would likely be pushed to disk. OR I could follow your steps above and push the `convert` process straight to disk. Just looking for confirmation of my understanding.

Comment: Yes, you should be able to do either. But you may need to adjust your policy.xml file to have enough disk space or RAM for your requirements.